# Create an environment with optional arguments

Tags: environments, arguments

I want to create environments with two optional arguments like that :

```
\begin{myenvir}[]
    Title

    #1
\end{myenvir}

\begin{myenvir}[s]
    Titles

    #1
\end{myenvir}

\begin{myenvir}[a]
    Title (with something)

    #1
\end{myenvir}

\begin{myenvir}[sa]
    Titles (with something)

    #1
\end{myenvir}
```

How can I do that ? I don't find anything on Internet to do that

EDIT : I was thinking about something like that :

```
% Pseudo-Declaration
\begin{envir}[#1]
    if #1 == a:
        Title (admis) % or admise but it depends of the envir
    elif #1 == s:
        Titles
    else:
        Titles (admis) % or admise
    % And then the text
\end{envir}
```

Comment: If you don't specify what the optional arguments should do, it's difficult to say anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that clear exactly what you want, as you're using `#1` in your example as if that would be used inside the environment, whereas that notation would only be used when *defining* the environment.

But I understand the situation correctly, at least in your response to gernot, the changes that need to be made will be different depending on each use of the environment.

So one approach is described below. Inside the environment you could use a special command with two alternatives that responds to the options set with the environment. It uses the `xstring` package for parsing the option, and `\NewDocumentEnvironment` command newly added to the kernel (see the [documentation for the xparse package](https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xparse.pdf) if need be),

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}% for \IfSubStr command

% set booleans for the options
\newif\ifmysoption
\newif\ifmyaoption

% define commands that respond to the options
\newcommand{\IfAOption}[2]{\ifmyaoption{#1}\else{#2}\fi}
\newcommand{\IfSOption}[2]{\ifmysoption{#1}\else{#2}\fi}

% define environment that sets the values of the booleans
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenvir}{o}{%
    \IfValueTF{#1}{% check if optional argument exists
        \IfSubStr{#1}{a}% check if it contains an a
            {\myaoptiontrue}% if so, set a option boolean true
            {\myaoptionfalse}% if not, set it false
        \IfSubStr{#1}{s}% check if it contains an s
            {\mysoptiontrue} % if so, set s option boolean true
            {\mysoptionfalse} % if not, set it false
    }{
        % no option given, so both are false
        \mysoptionfalse\myaoptionfalse
    }
}{%
}

\begin{document}

With no option:

\begin{myenvir}
Title\IfSOption{s}{}\IfAOption{ (Something)}{}
\end{myenvir}

\bigskip

With just ``a'':

\begin{myenvir}[a]
Title\IfSOption{s}{}\IfAOption{ (Something)}{}
\end{myenvir}

\bigskip

With just ``s'':

\begin{myenvir}[s]
Title\IfSOption{s}{}\IfAOption{ (Something)}{}
\end{myenvir}

\bigskip

With both:

\begin{myenvir}[sa]
Title\IfSOption{s}{}\IfAOption{ (Something)}{}
\end{myenvir}

\end{document}
```

[image: options output]

Comment: What he need are possibly theorem environments! He is a LaTeX beginner!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something along the following lines (though I'm not sure what you mean by `#1` in the sample uses of the environments)?

For every letter `X` representing an option (here `a` and `s`), define a command `\OptX` giving the default value (to be used if the option is not selected), as well as a command `\setOptX` that redefines `\OptX` to whatever it should signify when the option is selected. E.g., the definitions

```
\newcommand\Opts{}% default value
\newcommand\setOpts{\renewcommand\Opts{s}}
```

define an option `s` that makes `\Opts` expand to `s`; without the option, `\Opts` expands to nothing.

The options are handled by `\processOptions` that takes a string of option letters as an argument and calls the corresponding `\setOpt` commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\processOptions[1]{\processOptionsX#1\relax}
\newcommand\processOptionsX[1]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax
    \let\tmp\relax
  \else
    \csname setOpt#1\endcsname
    \let\tmp\processOptionsX
  \fi
  \tmp  
}
\newcommand\Opta{}% default value
\newcommand\setOpta{\renewcommand\Opta{ (with something)}}
\newcommand\Opts{}% default value
\newcommand\setOpts{\renewcommand\Opts{s}}
\newenvironment{myenvir}[1][]{%
  \processOptions{#1}%
  \begin{center}
}{%
  \end{center}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{myenvir}
    Title\Opts\Opta
\end{myenvir}
\begin{myenvir}[s]
    Title\Opts\Opta
\end{myenvir}
\begin{myenvir}[a]
    Title\Opts\Opta
\end{myenvir}
\begin{myenvir}[sa]
    Title\Opts\Opta
\end{myenvir}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't do that because "(with something)" can change in different environment (because gender grammar). I would more think about an "if" in each environment declaration but an "if" with the option in brackets